# How to add column with Colon : in column name in table using SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have two SQL server databases, `DB1` and `DB2`.

I am getting table and column names from `DB1` and need to create the same in `DB2`.

While using SQL query to insert table and column in `DB2`, I am getting an error

> Invalid Syntax near :

In `DB1`, the table name is `Person` and its columns are `P:ID`, `P:Address`.

This is the query which I used to create a new table with above column names in `DB2`:

```
INSERT TABLE NEW_PERSON (P:Name varchar(255), P:Address varchar(255))
```

I got references for MySQL database but my need is for SQL Server database.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Use Delimited identifiers. See [Database Identifiers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/database-identifiers?view=sql-server-ver16#classes-of-identifiers) section in the docs

Comment: Why are you prefixing all columns in the table with `P:` anyway? I suggest not doing that

Comment: If possible in any way try to avoid special characters in db object like table names, column names etc. It will make your life much easier. If that's not possible here tell us why.

Comment: You may rethink you syntax by the way. I doubt you created a table with a `INSERT` statement.

Comment: In this example , I hardcoded column names with colon but in my Case  i Got column names from SQL Server Database 1 .In server itself it has Column name with colon attached below image . 
I am getting all column names and stored in List . 
Then for creating new table with column names in List by using above query i am getting invalid syntax error .

COLUMN_NAME
ARAS:UNIQUENESS_HELPER
KEYED_NAME
ID

Answer (score 1):

P:Name will become [P:Name]

But please dont: special characters in database object names will lead to problems.